# How do you change the Active Storage Service url_expires_in timeout?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

When Active Storage creates a signed variant URL, it sets a default timeout of `5.minutes`. I really want to increase this, but I've been trawling Github issues, code diving and cannot find it anywhere. 
On line 44 of the services class a `class_attribute` is set, but how can this be overwritten?

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/activestorage/lib/active_storage/service.rb#L44

I'm using `url_for` to generate the signed variant links and there doesn't seem to be anyway to change the setting then. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you! :)

Comment: what do you think about inheritance? from service.rb class and override the value of url_expires_in?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Set `ActiveStorage::Service.url_expires_in` directly, e.g. in an initializer:

```
# config/initializers/active_storage.rb
ActiveStorage::Service.url_expires_in = 1.hour
```

Rails 6 will add `config.active_storage.service_urls_expire_in`:

```
# config/initializers/active_storage.rb
Rails.application.config.active_storage.service_urls_expire_in = 1.hour
```

Comment: Sir is there a limit for this configuration? Say can you do a `5.months` duration config?

Comment: @RicardoGreen According to https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31581 there is a limit of 1 week if you use S3.

Comment: @George Claghorn How to generate active_storage.rb file? I don't have active_storage.rb file in my hole project.

Comment: You would just create the file in your project folder. Use the path given in the comments config/initializers/active_storage.rb. Alternatively you can add this to your development.rb or production rb environment files as well.

Comment: How do you create a non-expiring link to the file?

Comment: @Corey You can now setup permanent links by setting up a public bucket. https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#public-access