# Active Storage Permanent Image URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm creating a google product listing for a website built in Ruby on Rails. The website has multiple stores with their own front ends so they're wanting a Google Product Feed for each store.

The issue I'm having is if I use url_for(image) then I get the URL for the image on that store. But the way active storage works it's on a temporary URL that lasts 5 minutes by default. So the links wouldn't work on the feed by the it's been processed.

The images are hosted on an S3 bucket so I can get the service_url. But Google doesn't like having the images coming from a separate domain to the store. Is there a way to have a permanent clean url from the stores domain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're after isn't easily possible. Active Storage doesn't seem to support permanent, non-expiring URLs: ["Request has expired" when using S3 with Active Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51502519/request-has-expired-when-using-s3-with-active-storage)

Depending on your setup, there might be a useful and (mostly) hack-free workaround. In my case, I've set a custom `show` action on the record that owns the file I want to link to:

`redirect_to url_for(@record_name.file)`

Then, using a path helper for the record `show` action in my app, as usual, just renders the thing I want via the expiring `url_for`.

Comment: what if i want to index the url for faster result ?!

Answer (score 2):

Try [rails_blob_url](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#redirect-mode)

```
rails_blob_url(image, disposition: "attachment")
```

**Update:** Link updated.

Comment: is this working? is the link permament with this flag?

Comment: I still get `X-Amz-Expires=300` in the url so I guess it expires

Comment: I have updated the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the full URL of an Active Storage attachment using the following:

```
polymorphic_url(@article.image.variant(resize: '800x600'))
```

This will provide a full url and not just the path and works well on **Rails 5.2+**